# NodeJs runs again to reach Number of Processes limit in cPanel

Tags: node.js, cpanel

I'm using shared hosting cPanel service.
I have ran a NodeJs application on server and everything is ok.
but after server backup runs in every day one NodeJs process add to the running processes and I can see these processes on terminal.

I have killed the processes but they came back after server backup!!!
I have write a code to exit from processes that run when port is busy:

```
tcpPortUsed.check(port, '127.0.0.1')
.then(function(inUse) {
  console.log(`Port ${port} usage: `+inUse);
  if (inUse) {
    process.exit();
  } else {
    app.listen(port, () =>
      console.log(`server is running on port: ${port}`)
    );
  }
}, function(err) {
  console.error('Error on check:', err.message);
});
```

but the problem has remained...
this is the terminal after I run ps aux:

```
user   5435  1.0  0.0   9916  1820 pts/0    S    16:50   0:00 /bin/bash -l
user   5752  0.0  0.0  49844  1684 pts/0    R+   16:50   0:00 ps aux
user  13658  0.0  0.1 1155556 36060 ?       Sl   05:15   0:06 lsnode:/home1/user/node-server/
user  32346  0.0  0.1 1091012 37944 ?       Sl   Jul04   0:05 lsnode:/home1/user/node-server/
```

Comment: Found any solution?

Comment: i have set a timeout with  `proccess.exit()` in the end of my code. my app will run for only 1 hour and after it will be exit until rerun with a user request.

Comment: Oh, this can't help in my case I guess, because my application will be having a lot of traffic and it may cause lots of never ending processes before executing `process.exit()`

Comment: no we will have only one proccess any way.

Comment: do this way to solve the problem. then you can buy a server and run your app on server easily

Comment: if you have any other question you can email me akaaymann@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you so much, please check your inbox

Comment: I have this exact problem. Tried several things on node script, but nothing really worked. Finally decided to run a cron job every 24 hours with command `pkill node` as a workaround. Site doesn't go down when I run the command either.